How do I automatically create multiple, 'stacked' tmux terminals in .tmux.conf upon startup using only ~/.tmux.conf?
How do I automatically create multiple terminals in .tmux.conf upon startup ideally using only ~/.tmux.conf? I want them stacked, not in separate panes or windows. GNU screen did this effortlessly.
I do not want multiple windows or a split window. I want five or six terminals (panes) under a single window, "stacked."
I have been using these settings for tmux for years but never had a reason to get fancy until now.
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
set -g default-shell /bin/bash
bind-key C-a last-window
bind-key k confirm kill-window

I tried this syntax but it failed to create any new terminals.
if-shell '[ -z "${TMUX}" ]' \
    "new-session -d -s my-session; \
     new-window -n 'Window1'; \
     new-window -n 'Window2'; \
     new-window -n 'Window3'; \
     select-window -t my-session:1; \
     attach-session -t my-session"

Tried this too:
# Start a new session with a window
new-session -s mysession -n zero -d
# Create additional windows
new-window -n 1 -d
new-window -n 2 -d
new-window -n 3 -d

No joy.
The Homebrew distribution includes a useful .tmux.conf example.
/opt/homebrew/opt/tmux/share/tmux
These lines do what I wanted, mostly. The only inconvenience now is I'm made to type, 'tmux attach' even when there's no tmux server running.
new -d -s0 -n zero
set -t0:0 monitor-activity on
set -t0:0 aggressive-resize on
neww -d -n one 'exec zsh'
setw -t0:1 aggressive-resize on
neww -d -n two 'exec zsh'
setw -t0:2 aggressive-resize on
neww -d -n three 'exec zsh'
setw -t0:3 aggressive-resize on
neww -d -n four 'exec zsh'
setw -t0:4 aggressive-resize on
neww -d -n five 'exec zsh'
setw -t0:5 aggressive-resize on


No matter what I do I can't start tmux with session named "default."
tmux starts and I can Ctrl-s into the session and only then are the windows accessible.
if-shell "tmux has-session -t default 2>/dev/null" "attach-session -t default" 
"new-session -d -s default -n window1; 
new-window -t default:1 -n window2; 
new-window -t default:2 -n window3; 
new-window -t default:3 -n window4; 
attach-session -t default"

Oh, now I see that the terminals are called panes. I thought they were panes if they were sub-windows within a larger, graphical window. Each terminal is a pane, whether or not it's in the foreground. Got it!
